# Basic table issue: one <td> per <tr> others being pushed out

Tags: html, layout, html-table, html-email

I'm writing an email so I'm forced to work within table layouts. I have a table with some images that are supposed to sit side by side but it seems to be setting one at the full width of the table, and pushing the other two out.

```html
    <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0px">
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <a href="google.com" ><img alt="saleinfo" 
       src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/75704/JPs-Slices/advenstar-dec/body.jpg"></img></a>
      </td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
       <a href="google.com"><img alt="saleinfo" 
       src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/75704/JPs-Slices/advenstar-dec/pail.jpg"></img></a>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="google.com" ><img alt="saleinfo" 
       src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/75704/JPs-Slices/advenstar-dec/stat-mat.jpg"></img></a>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="google.com" ><img alt="saleinfo" 
       src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/75704/JPs-Slices/advenstar-dec/valet.jpg"></img></a>
      </td>        
 </tbody>
</table>
```

From my troubleshooting, I found that it doesn't have the same effect if you remove the top image.

Comment: use inline css styling to set a max width and a percentage width for the images and table/td's. Don't use a fixed width if at all possible.

Comment: HTML stickler: `</img>` is an invalid closing tag; they can safely be removed.

Comment: @fred -ii- Because its an email, CSS isn't much of an option as far as i understand?

Comment: you can use inline css in emails there's no problem with that, I use it all the time. You can't expect the images to fit in any browser size/screen size here. I was a web designer before I was a web "developer" ;-) and still am.

Comment: i'm sort of juggling a few different things here, I've stripped fixed 600px but that didn't exactly fix it. I don't exactly want to run math for %'s i'm Graham sort of worked, but it compressed the text down with it. so i'm trying to just break it up into multiple tables. I'm sure there's a better way, but i think it may work...

Comment: I tested Graham's possible solution and all the images lined up well.

Comment: *"but it compressed the text down with it."* - you need to edit your question then with some sample text. We don't know how it's all supposed to tie in together. Do up a Lorep ipsum example with the same amount of letters/words.

Comment: Everything is under control at this point thanks a whole bunch to all involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `colspan="3"` to the `td` in the first `tr`

Answer (score 0):

`colspan` can cause spacing issues in some environments, so be wary of that. I would nest another table inside each row, then put my content `td`s inside that.

Also, you are missing a closing `/tr` for the second row